# Sorting a list of objects in python on basis of attribute's three different value?

Tags: python, sorting, jquery-ui-sortable

I have  a list of objects.Every object has an attribute "priority" whose value could be low,medium,high.I would need to sort the list of objects so that objects with priority "high" comes first in list and then objects with priority "medium" and lastly  objects with priority "low".I know I can do this using few for loops , but I want a pythonic solution that is fast and effective.sorry but i am a beginner in python.

Comment: http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
score = dict(high=0, medium=1, low=2)
mylist.sort(key=lambda x: score[x.priority])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. Upvoted for the pythonic solution.

I used the sorted variant.

```
sorted(myList, key = lambda x : score[x.priority])
```